# be equal to in this definition

Tags: verbs, adjectives, reduced-relative-clauses, whiz-deletion

I checked the word centimetre in a dictionary and had: *“a metric unit of length, equal to one hundredth of a metre.”*

Why is it **equal to**, shouldn’t it be **be equal to**? Is it a short version for (which is) equal to..? On Merriam Webster it’s the same, “*a unit of length equal to ¹/₁₀₀ meter*“, is there any omission out there?

Comment: Look up "whiz-deletion"

Comment: _A unit of length, be equal to..._ would be ungrammatical.

Comment: @KateBunting I meant “ a unit of length which is equal to...” I wondered if which is is omitted.

Comment: It is. As @gotube suggests, this is ['whiz-deletion'](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/whiz-deletion/info)